# TWS API historical data volume is incorrect

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, tws

i'm working TWS API, trying to get get historical data of a stock using:

```
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime('14/11/19', '%d/%m/%y')
queryTime0 = date_time_obj.strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
reqHistoricalData(id, contract, queryTime0, "52 W", "1 day", "TRADES", 1, 1, False, [])
```

example:

```
self.reqHistoricalData(id, contract, queryTime0, "3 D", "1 day", "TRADES", 1, 1, False, [])
HistoricalData. ReqId: 1   DNN BarData. Date: 20191112, Open: 0.450100, High: 0.450100, Low: 0.450100, Close: 0.450100, Volume: 5, Average: 0.450100, BarCount: 3
```

comparing the volume to yahoo chart, the volume in that day is more than 100k shares, it doesn't make any sense, even if i multiply it by 100.
some dates will not return data for specified date by using TRADES, only if i used MIDPOINT.
is there another api to use or am i using it incorrectly ?

Comment: Are you subscribed to all the right sources? Also show the contract specs.

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you found how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, that's intended as IBKR has filtered historical data as per their API page.

-> Note: IB's historical data feed is filtered for some types of trades which generally occur away from the NBBO such as combos, block trades, and derivatives. For that reason the historical data volume will be lower than an unfiltered historical data feed.

Source: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/historical_bars.html